# What is Self Join and how to write self join for more than 3 tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

I know about inner join, left join ,right join, outer join.
What is self join? 
Any one explain me what is self join and it uses and also where to use.

Then also i want to know how to join more than three tables using self join.

Eg **Customer Table**

1)CustomerID uniqueidentifier primary key not null,
2)CustomerName Varchar(100),
3)CustomerTypeID uniqueidentifier null,

**CustomerType**

1)CustomerTypeID uniqueidentifier primary key not null 
2)CustomerType varchar null

**CustomerAddress Table**

1)CustomerAddressID  uniqueidentifier primary key not null
2)CustomerID uniqueidentifier null,
3)AddressID uniqueidentifier null,

**Address**

1)AddressID uniqueidentifier primary key not null,
2)Street varchar(100) null,
3)Location varchar(100) null,
4)Place varchar(100), null,
5)AreaID uniqueidentifier null,
6)PinCode Varchar(100)

**Area**

1)AreaID uniqueidentifier primary key not null,
2)Area Varchar(100)

Here i mention some tables. Now i want to display CustomerName , CustomerType, Street,Place,Location, Area, PinCode. Now how i put self join for these tables . please any one explain this concept.

Answer (score 0):

Self join is joining a table to itself. This is done in a scenario like below-

**`TableProductCategory`**

---

```
ID     CategoryName ParentCategoryID

1      Clothes       NULL
2      Jeans         1
3      Shorts        1
```

So in such a scenario, if you need to list Name of categories with their parent category name you'd use a self join like below

```
Select A.CategoryName, B.CategoryName as ParentCategoryName
from
TableProductCategory A LEFT JOIN TableProductCategory B
on A.ParentCategoryID=B.ID
```

For your requirement

> CustomerName , CustomerType, Street,Place,Location, Area, PinCode

you need to use simple `LEFT JOIN`  like query below

```
Select 
C.CustomerName, 
T.CustomerType, 
A.Street, 
A.Place, 
A.Location,
AA.Area, 
A.Pincode
From 
  Customer C 
   LEFT JOIN CustomerType T on C.CustomerTypeID=T.CustomerTypeID
   LEFT JOIN CustomerAddress CA on C.CustomerID =CA.CustomerID 
   LEFT JOIN Address A on A.AddressID=CA.AddressID
   LEFT JOIN Area AA on AA.AreaID=A.AreaID
```